Error on passing view data to partial view in ASP.NET Core after update of Visual Studio
I am pretty new to C# and ASP.NET Core, but experienced in VB.NET. I can't figure out the following problem.
This is code I got from my colleague. It ran fine on my PC. After updating my Visual Studio IDE from 16.9 to 17.10, I get all sorts of errors. The code passes inline view data to a partial view.
This is a small part of the view:
<partial name="Productiegegevens_Cel" view-data='@new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData)
{
    { "Spacing", "mb-1" },
    { "Label", "Melk prijs (€/100kg)" },
    { "Naam", "melk_prijs" },
    { "Data", Model.Voerefficientie1.productiegegevens.melk_prijs.ToString("n2") },
    { "Data_alt", Model.Voerefficientie2 != null ? Model.Voerefficientie2.productiegegevens.melk_prijs.ToString("n2") : null },
    { "Append", @Model.Voerefficientie1.productiegegevens.melk_prijs_huidig.ToString("n2") }
}' />

In VS 17.10, I get all kinds of weird errors:
Error list
Even weirder still, when is double click the error message, it jumps to the right code and the error in the error window disappears. When I compile the code the error messages reappear and the compiler stops with errors.
When I create a viewdata object and pass it to the partial view it work fine. This would be a work-around except for the fact that my code contains al lot of this peaces of code. Was this code legit to begin with, or was is never meant to run?
I have created a new project, imported the code-files. I saw the same behavior. It is reproducible on both my computers. One running Windows 11 the other running Windows 11.
Can someone shed light on this problem for me? I am in the dark here. Thanks, Erik

Issues related to Visual Studio are often best (also) reported using the built in Feedback option. It is my experience that they take such reports seriously.

I would try to run "Clean Solution" and then "Build" to see if that helps

Nuke your bin and obj directories. Make sure you're using the right version of the .NET SDK (which should be specified in your Solution's global.json file).

Thanks for all the suggestions. These are much appropriated. Sadly none of them got me the result I hoped for. I rewrote my code to make it all work again.
